# Как сделать исскуственное нажатие на клавишу по коду?

Tags: javascript

На https://example.com через Ctrl+Shift+I вводится код на js, "нажимающий" на клавишу.

```
function key(code_of_key){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для симуляции искусственного нажатия на клавишу можно использовать события клавиатуры. Вот пример кода, который демонстрирует, как это можно сделать:

```
// Создаем новое событие клавиатуры для нажатия на клавишу
let event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
  key: 'Enter', // Здесь можно указать нужную клавишу
  keyCode: 13, // Дополнительно можно указать код клавиши
  which: 13 // Дополнительно можно указать код клавиши
});

// Симулируем нажатие на клавишу, вызвав событие на целевом элементе или на документе
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

этот код симулирует нажатие на клавишу в контексте документа. Если нужно симулировать нажатие на конкретном элементе (например, поле ввода) нужно будет вызвать событие на этом элементе, а не на document.